# react-native eject not working for react-native 0.60.0

Tags: react-native

Is **react-native eject** is not working anymore ? is it completely removed from the react-native? I am using **react-native version 0.60.0**.

I can't even find it in the **react-native help**.

Please check the image for more reference:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Same here. In this moment, have a brand new backup of your project and then copy the android and ios folder, is the better way to regenerate those folders... unfortunately

**UPDATE**

```
react-native upgrade --legacy true
```

Answer (score 3):

Firstly you would need to install react-native-eject then you can run react-native eject.
Simply do these:

```
npm i react-native-eject
```

or

```
yarn add react-native-eject
```

then run:

```
react-native eject
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the `eject` command [was removed](https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/pull/275) from `react-native` recently (March 28, 2019).

Comment: any workaround you know to this? They can just simply remove and and ignore it despite the comments left by devs, shame.

Answer (score 0):

React Native had this command in the previous version. Running this command will check if the ios and android directories exist and then rebuild whichever one is missing.

**react-native eject <=0.59.0**

Now you should use the **react-native upgrade --legacy true** command to back up your android folders or ios as the case may be as this command will replace your files.

Answer (score -1):

`eject` isn't part of `react-native`, but rather `expo`. To eject, you can run:

```
npm run eject
```

Comment: You need an eject.js script for this code to work, however seeing the eject method is deprecated, it won't be of any use.

Answer (score -1):

react-native eject has been deprecated use npx react-native eject its working

Comment: This won't work either. It returns the error Cannot find module '@react-native-community/cli/build/tools/generator/copyProjectTemplateAndReplace' with a long list of required stack