# How can i regenerate ios and android folder?

Tags: android, ios, react-native

How can I regenerate ios and android folder in React Native project?

react-native-cli: 2.0.1 react-native: 0.61.2

> ❯ react-native eject error Unrecognized command "eject". info Run
>   "react-native --help" to see a list of all available commands.
>
> ❯ react-native upgrade --legacy true error: unknown option `--legacy'

Comment: isn't eject an `expo` command?

Comment: I am using react-native cli , when i run react-native eject am getting error unrecognized command. @lvan

Comment: i am new in react-native, actually i am trying to add icon and splashscreen

Comment: Did you create the app using expo? Cause react-native eject got removed in latest versions. Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56968147/react-native-eject-not-working-for-react-native-0-60-0

Comment: try running `expo eject`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I regenerate ios folder in React Native project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42506068/how-can-i-regenerate-ios-folder-in-react-native-project)

Comment: no i created project using react-native cli .. yeah react-native eject got removed instead of using eject i used upgrade but still getting unknown option --legacy ..@Auticcat

Comment: command not found because i am not using expo i am using cli. @LonelyCpp

Answer (score 2):

You can init a new project that's named the same in another folder and copy ios dir over:

## inside YourProjectName directory

```
npx react-native init YourProjectName
mv YourProjectName/ios ios
rm -rf YourProjectName
```

Make sure you have clean git history before doing so, in case you need to revert

Answer (score -1):

To Regenerate ios and android folder in React Native project?

1.If you are using react-native <=0.59.0
Then **react-native eject**

React-native had this command in the previous version. Running this command will check if the ios and android directories exist and then rebuild whichever one is missing.

sudo rm -rf android/ ios/

react-native eject // Will create new Android and IOS folder.

react-native link

react-native run-android

2.If you are using react-native >=0.60.0
Then **react-native upgrade --legacy true**

Now you should use the react-native upgrade --legacy true command to back up your android folders or ios as the case may be as this command will replace your files.

Comment: OP already tried to use `react-native upgrade --legacy true` but gets the error `react-native upgrade --legacy true error: unknown option `--legacy'`